# MySQL - collect everything and exclude

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

```
idevent | idportal | iduser | idrole | idrecipient | recipient_idrole | idfile | type | is_deleted | add_date | shared_with_users
```

**shared_with_users** column stores serialize array - `a:3:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"3";i:2;s:1:"4";}`

I need to collect all the records for **idportal** and exclude records where  **shared_with_users** doesn’t contain for example **i:0**. Is this possible?

The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE idportal = 1 *EXLUDE i:0 FROM shared_with_users*
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE idportal = 1 AND shared_with_users NOT LIKE '%i:0%'
```

Comment: I forgot to add how the query should look. Please take a look at edited question.

Comment: I updated the query. If it's still not what you are looking for, please add sample data and the desired result to your question.